# Scheduling using SQL Server Service Broker to call a stored procedure after specific time period

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have table in which data is inserted every time an employee punches in or out. When the data is inserted another table is updated. Currently I am doing this using a stored procedure that runs every minute by means of a scheduled SQL Server Agent job.

It works ok, but running it every minute is unnecessary during specially during off-peak times.

Is there a way to make the stored procedure run every minute only if data is inserted into table? Triggers might not work because I do not want the stored procedure to run immediately after the insert but after specified interval like a minute or so, so that I can update multiple punches at once.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to keep track of the last scan and only run your routine when there is work to be done. One minute is fine for polling. The only thing you need to do to is save the last scan date and compare against the punch out/in time. However, be mindful that your logic must be able to handle an errant last scan date, for example it was changed to one year ago by accident.